# symfony2 bundle install assets

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I've made a couple bundles of my own, and they are installing correctly with composer, but I cannot seem to figure out how to make the assets contained in the bundles install the assets they contain in /Resources/public/ to be installed into the web/bundles/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the symlink option defined in your composer.json file?

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
}
```

That last line tells symfony to make asset references symlinks to the public folders. Removing `"symfony-assets-install": "symlink"` ***should*** install assets in the web/bundles folder.

Comment: I do not have the 'symfony-assets-install' in my composer.json. I've tried adding those lines to both the project composer.json (which seems for force the symlink istall instead of the hardinstall) and the composer.json for my bundle, but I only get assets for the FrameworkBundle and DistributionBundle when I run composer update, nothing for my custom bundle. FWIW I'm using apache+git to host the custom bundle, not Packagist or Satis.